# Are there any good online training sites/videos for learning subversion?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, windows-xp, svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to learn subversion as best as possible but honestly anything I have read makes very little sense. I feel like I need a crash course in:

1. What subversion is?
2. How to install it.
3. How to use it.
4. Recommendations for best interfaces

I have a Media Temple DV 3.5 server running Subversion version 1.6.12 and while I know how to upgrade to 1.6.17, I have no idea what the implications are or if it is even necessry. Similarly, even though installed, I have zero idea how to use it or really what the benefits of using it would be. YUM's latest repo verion is 1.6.12 so it makes me think updating is not necessary at this time. My base understanding is version control for code but once I have my locally built files updated onto my server's subversion directory, how do I then put that into production code?

I know this seems basic and dumb perhaps but I am wiling to even pay for an online course/video learning piece which fully explains what subversion is and how to use it.

Even [this page](http://www.hossainkhan.info/content/installing-svn-trac-media-temple-dv-35-running-centos-53) does a 'good' job of explaining the steps somebody went through to get subversion running on their system but it does not explain how things work, is likely outdated, and uses manual installs outside of the typical YUM CentOS process so makes me think it could be unstable.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ ?  That's the "book" I've read 7 years ago to learn subversion, and still the reference I go to today if I get stuck on something.  It should be more than enough to cover your 1 and 3.